# List disks/volumes

Tags: terminal, disk, devices

Is there a terminal command to display the mounted disks like that:
[image]

I only need the logical name, size and device name.
If this isn't possible, size and device name would be enough to display.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

```
lsblk -o path,size,model --nodeps
```

seems to do exactly what you requested, but for all disks, not just mounted ones.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious one: `mount` it would give the exactly same picture as you want.

There is also `findmnt`.

And do not forget `man mount` and `man findmnt` for options.